# Draw plotly Lines on a bar graph with arbitrary x values

Tags: angular, plotly, plotly.js

This is what my bar graph looks like:

[image]

And below is the shapes dict I am using inside the larger layout object:

```
        this.sla_model = 60 // This is some arbitrary value that changes over time.

        {
            type: 'line',
            x0: -1,
            y0: this.sla_model.mtta_lower*60,
            y1: this.sla_model.mtta_lower*60,
            line: {
                color: 'yellow',
            }
        }
```

As you can see, I am unsure as to what to put for the x0 and x1 values in the graph, and I some times get the horizontal like that doesnt properly cover the entire graph. Any work arounds for this?

Comment: Is your question "How do I draw a horizontal line that spans the entire graph"?

Comment: yes, how do i do that